# Cordova file plugin not writing to file

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am currently working with the Cordova (Cordova version 3.4.1) file plugin and I am having some trouble getting it to work on Android.  I've gone through the documentation on the plugin and on the HTML5 file storage API, (as well as several StackOverflow posts - most of them advise to install the plugin first, which I already have done) and I cannot find anything relating to the issue I'm having.

I am building an app (Android for now, iOS later) that receives push notifications.  The notifications are working fine, but I want to add the ability for users to disable these push notifications.  I'd like to store this data in the phone somewhere, and since there is not yet a plugin for using SharedPreferences, I'm writing the user's notification preferences to a file on the phone.  (I don't want to query our server to find out the notification preferences.)

So, I've set up things based on this tutorial: http://selinosblog.com/2014/01/27/saving-and-deleting-images-via-phonegaps-file-api/ along with the Cordova docs.  Here's the code I'm using for interacting with the file system:

```
var FileIO = {
    initializeFileSystem: function() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, FileIO.gotFS, FileIO.errorHandler);
    },

    gotFS : function(fileSystem) {
        console.log("FILE SYSTEM IS ", fileSystem.name);

        gFileSystem = fileSystem;
        FileIO.getFile({create : true}, FileIO.writeFile);
    },

    getFile : function(params, success) {
        gFileSystem.root.getFile('notification_preferences.txt', params, success, FileIO.errorHandler);
    },

    writeFile : function(fileEntry) {
        console.log(fileEntry);
        console.log('FILE URL: ' + fileEntry.toUrl());
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            var blob = new Blob(['Lorem Ipsum'], {type: 'text/plain'});
            fileWriter.write(blob);
        }, errorCallback);
    },

    readFile : function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                console.log('CONTENTS OF FILE: ', e.target.result)
            };
            reader.readAsText(file, 'text/plain');
        }, errorCallback);
    },

    removeFile : function(fileEntry){
        fileEntry.remove();
    },

// simple error handler
    errorHandler : function(e) {
        var msg = '';
        switch (e.code) {
            case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
                msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
                break;
            case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
                break;
            case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
                msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
                break;
            case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
                msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
                break;
            case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
                msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
                break;
            default:
                msg = e.code;
                break;
        }
        console.log('Error: ' + msg);
    }
};
```

Now, this is the error I get when I try to write to the file:

```
D/CordovaLog( 2871): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1034 : processMessage failed: 
Message: S01 File30696438 {"fullPath":"\/\/notification_preferences.txt","filesystemName":"temporary",
"isDirectory":false,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/org.changefactor.pgdemo\/cache\/notification_preferences.txt",
"filesystem":0,"isFile":true,"name":"notification_preferences.txt"}
```

I can't figure out what's happening or what I'm doing wrong.  Is there an easier way to store this data?  Is something wrong with the configuration?

Comment: What code are you using to write the file? can you include that as well?

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` makes more sense with regard to storing user preferences. That is, unless you intend on generating a *lot* of user preferences (like > 5MB).